# saleor-frontend product page not loading due to TypeError

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, saleor

I've deployed [saleor](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor) on an Ubuntu instance, let's say at example.com. I've deployed [saleor-storefront](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront) to Netlify, at frontend.example.com. I've created a new product in it, with prices filled in.

When I search for the product using the search bar on saleor-frontend, it manages to find it. But, the product page on saleor-storefront at frontend.example.com/product/awesome-tee/1/ does not load. Console shows this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (index.tsx:43)
    at uo (react-dom.production.min.js:132)
    at ki (react-dom.production.min.js:167)
    at Ri (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
    at Qa (react-dom.production.min.js:232)
    at $a (react-dom.production.min.js:233)
    at Is (react-dom.production.min.js:249)
    at Ps (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at ws (react-dom.production.min.js:245)
    at Za (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
```

(*Edit 20 Sep 2019, 13:56: I didn't change anything, went to bed, woke up, and now the page shows "Page not found".*)

However, the page on the sample site at example.com/en/products/awesome-tee/1/ loads just fine.

I'm new to Saleor and React so the code is quite alien to me for now. Nonetheless, I reasoned that it might be a graphql query problem so I took a look at saleor-storefront/src/views/Product/queries.ts. First, I tried deleting all the code that might be related to price, for example:

```
price {
      currency
      amount
      localized
    }
```

It didn't change anything.

Then, I found a typo in `productVariatnsQuery` that I really didn't think was an issue. I fixed it anyway and it didn't solve the problem. I have not identified anything else that might be causing the TypeError.

How should I go about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I re-ran the container and it worked. I originally deployed the back end in my Ubuntu instance with `docker-compose up -d`. So, I did `docker-compose down`, deleted the saleor_web_1 container and removed its saleor_web image. Then did `docker-compose up -d` again to rebuild and run the container.

Now it works. I think. I'm not entirely sure because there are other issues now and I don't know if they are related. For instance, the storefront product page loads but it has no description on it. The sample site product page has a description though.

Not sure if I should delete this question.